# What is the purpose of committing a solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, commit

While looking at the available options for committing to Git in Visual Studio 2013, I've seen that one can commit a solution. I did a quick test with a small solution, the option to commit the solution appears only when a new project is added to it.

My conclusion is that the whole purpose of committing a solution is to track added or removed projects.

Is this correct or are there other purposes for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I include the solution file in the git repository of my project as that allows some one with visual studio to down load my repository open the solution and be able to build it without having to reconfigure my build settings. I think they are most important when you have multiple projects in one solution. For instance I have  broken my solution up into multiple projects most of which are libraries that are used by the main project of that solution. Without the solution file these projects wouldn't be connected into one solution and the end user would have to connect them together their selves.

Comment: But you make sure that you do nothing else than adding a project or configuring the solution during this commit, right ?

Comment: You could if you like. With git you can add single files at a time and only commit that one. It doesn't break anything if you upload it with other changes as well. I usually like to keep each commit in a working state and committing only the solution file on it's own might cause problems if it's settings aren't consistent with the old  versions of files. But what ever makes the most sense with your workflow.